# jQueryMobile: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_trigger' of undefined

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am using jQuery Mobile with backbone.js. when i load home page i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_trigger' of undefined
```

this is what i do to load home page.
in routes.js:

```
routes:{
    '':'home',
}
home:function () {
    new HomeView();
    this.changePage(new HomeContentView());
},
changePage:function (page) {
    $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'page');
    console.log($(page.el));
    page.render();
    $('body').append($(page.el));
    var transition = $.mobile.defaultPageTransition;
    if (this.firstPage) {
        transition = 'none';
        this.firstPage = false;
    }
    $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash:false, transition: transition});
}
```

in view.js

```
window.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
template : Handlebars.compile($('#home').html()),
render : function (eventname) {
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    this.header = new HeaderElement();
    this.$el.find('div.header_element').append(this.header.$el);
    this.footer = new FooterElement();
    this.$el.find('div.footer_element').append(this.footer.$el);
    return this;
}
});


window.HomeContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.collection = new Fan();
        this.template = Handlebars.compile(tpl.get('elements/home'));
        //~ console.log(tpl.get('home'));
        this.collection.on("reset",this.render,this);
        this.init = true;

        if (this.init) {
            upLimit = 1;
            this.collection.index();
            this.init = false;
        }
    },
    el: '#home_content_view',
    render : function (eventName) {
        var self = this;
        var js = (self.collection.toJSON())[0];
        console.log(js);

        $('#home_content_view').html(self.template(js));
        $('#home_content_view').trigger("create");
    }
});
```

in home.html

```
<div data-role="content">
hi
</div>
```

error stack trace:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_trigger' of undefined jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js:2843
transitionPages jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js:2843
$.mobile.changePage jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js:3465
Backbone.Router.extend.changePage routes.js:153
Backbone.Router.extend.home routes.js:37
f.extend.route backbone-min.js:27
f.extend.loadUrl backbone-min.js:32
b.some.b.any underscore-min.js:14
f.extend.loadUrl backbone-min.js:32
f.extend.start backbone-min.js:31
(anonymous function) routes.js:162
$.ajax.success view.js:29
v.Callbacks.l jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
v.Callbacks.c.fireWith jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
T jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
v.support.ajax.v.ajaxTransport.send.r jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
```

other pages are rendered correctly. Only home page is giving me trouble.
Where am i getting wrong? How do i solve this?

Comment: Try using the recent version of Jquery-mobile 1.3.0

Comment: I've got the same error without Backbone, but dynamically generating a page. I'm deleting a page and recreating again, but the changePage fails.

Answer (score 6):

I think that error might be because jQuery Mobile needs an element in place to transition out on `changePage`. It's a hack, but putting an empty `div` with the `data-role` attribute set to 'page' in your index.html should resolve it:

```
<body>
    <!-- jQM seems to need a page to exist in the document before it transitions to the first dynamically generated one -->
    <div data-role="page"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This works beautifully, why is it not voted the answer??

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of the problem to be jquery-mobile version 1.3.0.  When I fall back to either JSM 1.2.0 or 1.2.1, the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trigger' of undefined" problem goes away.

BTW, I am not using Backbone, but I get the problem.