# jQuery mobile form stuck on loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I was trying to create simple form on `jQuery` mobile and i've no idea why its stuck on the loading bubble it makes.

Here is the form code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>X</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="min_set.js"></script>-->
</head>


<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Sign up</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <form data-ajax="false" action="register.php" id="signup_form" method="post" >
            <input type="text" name="name" id="basic"   placeholder="Username" />


            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                   <legend>Agree to the terms:</legend>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-agree" id="checkbox-agree" class="custom" />
                </fieldset>
                   <label for="checkbox-agree">I agree</label>

                 <button type="submit" id="submit" theme="c">Submit</button>

            </div>

        </form>

    </div>

<div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
<h3>X</h3>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And its just stuck on the loading bubble without moving to the register.php page, I also did `data-ajax="false"` but seems to be the same result.

Comment: any error in console/network tab?

Comment: yes, this is the error im getting, but i dont really understand what its mean Oo

thanks
http://oi58.tinypic.com/21bj9xf.jpg

Comment: You should then search for this error, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838056/jquerymobile-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-trigger-of-undefined

Comment: Well, in my code you can see I've the line `<div data-role="page"></div>` so i dont think its the same problem.

Comment: try using newer jQM versions.